# Polymer paper-menu-dropdown bug

Tags: html, polymer

On Google Chrome the dropdown menu (when clicked) gets displayed in the middle of the screen then gets aligned properly above the icon menu. Here's an image that will describe it better.

[image]
[image]

I am sure that it's not a CSS problem because it works perfectly normal on FireFox but not on Chrome.

Code:

```
<paper-toolbar class="navbar-inverse">

  <paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item><a href="#">Questions</a></paper-item>
        <paper-item><a href="#">Opinions</a></paper-item>
        <paper-item><a href="#">Codes</a></paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
  </paper-menu-button>

  <span class="title">CodeIts</span>
  <ul class="navbar-nav list-inline">
    <li>
        <paper-button class="signup" ink="circle">Sign up</paper-button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <paper-button class="login" ink="circle">Log in</paper-button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</paper-toolbar>
```